# RoR modal from submit?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

Does anyone know how to get a modal to open from a button_tag or submit_tag on RoR instead of redirecting to another page when submitting a form?

Ex:

```
 <%= form_tag(compare_products_path, :id => 'product-select', remote: true) do %>
  <%= button_tag "Compare",id:'compare-button', class: 'pull-right btn btn-default'%>
  <%= check_box_tag "products[]", product.id %>
```

the button_tag should open a modal with content from products/compare

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a more complicated question to answer without knowing what your project is like, but in general:

You need to provide a javascript response in the controller method.

```
def method_here
  # Other method stuff
  repsond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then provide a view that corresponds with the method name as usual, except make it a .js or .coffee file instead of haml or slim or whatever template you're using.

Use that JS file to trigger a modal opening.